# Brightness problems on ubuntu15.10 for UEFI compatible laptop

Tags: brightness, ubuntu-gnome, nouveau

I have recently installed Ubuntu 15.10 alongside Windows 8.1 with UEFI compatibility i had to disable `nouveau.modeset` now i cant reduce my brightness on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you're booted with `nouveau.modeset=0`, you need to actually install some working graphics drivers.

Open the Additional Drivers app by seearching for it, and let it scan. Once some options pop up, choose the newest driver version that ends with `(proprietary)` and click the <kbd>Apply</kbd> button to install the driver.

Reboot after it installs. You won't need to use the `nouveau.modeset=0` flag anymore, and your brightness should work.